# シンタックスハイライトを維持して印刷したい

Tags: jupyter-notebook

よろしくお願いします

jupyter notebookの印刷を試みています．

print previewでは，シンタックスハイライトの効いたページが表示されるのですが，

ブラウザの印刷設定に進むと，ハイライトの消えた白黒のページとなってしまい，そのまま印刷されてしまいます．

シンタックスハイライトを維持したまま，ノートブックを印刷する方法はありませんでしょうか？

*追記*
jupyter notebookのバージョンは5.7.0
使用ブラウザは，FireFox 65.0(64ビット)です．
印刷設定ですが，カラー印刷設定となっています．

プリントプレビューでは，以下のようにハイライトが効いています．
[image: プリントプレビューでの表示]
印刷画面に進むと，カラー印刷にしていても，次のようになってしまっています．
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 手元の環境では正常に印刷可能そうでした（PDFとして一旦保存した結果、色付きのまま保存された）。印刷設定で白黒に設定していませんか？また、jupyter notebookやブラウザのバージョンを記載すると良いかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます．情報を追記しました．また，印刷設定についてですが，カラー印刷となっていました．

Answer (score 4, accepted):

調べた結果、Jupyter notebookでは明示的に印刷時に白黒になるように設定されているようです。

[python - Printing iPython Notebook preview in color? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969333/printing-ipython-notebook-preview-in-color)
[Color printing should be an option (or should be the default?) · Issue #840 · jupyter/notebook](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/840#issuecomment-179952484)

そして、2つの解決策があります。

1. HTMLとして出力して、 `@media print` の中の `!important;color:#000` という部分を削除し、それをブラウザで開き直して印刷する

   - プリンタ設定のモノクロ化する部分を無理やり削除する方法になります。
2. Jupyterlabを使う

   - Jupyter notebookの開発は既に終了しており、こちらが後継として開発されています。Jupyterlabでは、印刷時にカラーのまま印刷できることを先程自分がコメントした時点で確認済みです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．1の方法で印刷することができました．2のJupyterlabですが，旧notebookであったPrint previewがなくなっており，うまく印刷することが出来ませんでした．重ねての質問となってしまい申し訳ありませんが，どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか．JupyterLabのヴァージョンは0.35.3です．

Comment: Jupyterlabの印刷については本件と別の質問になるため、新しく質問を作成して切り分けてください

Comment: かしこまりました。丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。