# JupyterLabでの印刷

Tags: jupyter-notebook

お世話になります。

JupyterLabではnotebookにあった'print preview'コマンドが見当たないのですが、なくなってしまったのでしょうか。
現在は、一度htmlとして出力する事で印刷しています。
より良い方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 関連： https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/52629/%E3%82%B7%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%83%8F%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E7%B6%AD%E6%8C%81%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E5%8D%B0%E5%88%B7%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

タブごとの印刷機能については、現在Issueとして上がっているもののまだ実装されていないようです。

[Make any tab printable by itself · Issue #822 · jupyterlab/jupyterlab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/822)
[Handle printing of documents in browser · Issue #1314 · jupyterlab/jupyterlab](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1314)

このため、ノートブック部分以外（メニューバーなどのUI）が含まれる形式で印刷していただくか、一旦PDFなどの形式にエクスポートして印刷する必要があります。